# Data attribute as callback identifier

Tags: javascript, html

Having a HTML/css/Javascript based menu system.

The menus themselves are dynamically built using Javascript and ends up in something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon icon-star">&nbsp;</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon icon-boat">&nbsp;</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon icon-bike">&nbsp;</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I also plan to have a serverside version (build the menus using server script) and / or static versions. Have to do some benchmarks when it is all up and running.

The span holds icons by sprite background.

Now, instead of adding event listener to each menu entry I add one to the `UL` and on klick or key-down I locate the selected menu entry from the event. Typically:

```
a = event.target;

// Find the LI element.
for (li = a; li && li.nodeName != "LI"; li = li.parentNode)
    ;

// Find the anchor (Typically if the span was clicked).
if (a.nodeName !== 'A')
    for (; a && a.nodeName != "A"; a = a.parentNode)
        ;
```

This works fine but the question becomes how to identify which action should be taken – as in which menu entry was clicked.

***Would it be OK to use the `data-` tag?***

Typically something like:

```
<a href="#" data-menu="1">...
```

And then use a `switch` routine to determine menu entry.

My initial thought was to use ID's, but as I see it using the `data-` attribute is more flexible and less prone for clashes and complications.

Initially the idea behind attaching only one event listener per menu is to lessen the load at page load and instead do the *finding* when menu entry are clicked as by then in most cases that can take precedence when it comes to resource usage. I also need to style the `LI` element by adding/removing a `.menu_selected` class upon menu selection.

I'm a bit unsure about the design as a whole. It works fine by the (*few*) test I have done, but there might be some caveats I'm not seeing.

This is targeting never browsers only. HTML5 + canvas.

*… and now I'm unsure how good a question this is, but I'll give it a try and delete if not appropriate.*

Comment: Of course it is OK to use `data-*` attributes, that what they are there for. Instead of a `switch` statement, you can use a map and simply look up the function / action by key, e.g. `actions[ele.getAttribute('data-id')]();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it be OK to use the `data-` tag?

Certainly, you can delegate events on *any* selector.

The jQuery library makes this much easier too:

```
$('ul').on('click', '[data-menu]', function () {
    ...do awesome stuff...
});
```

The code above binds a click handler to any and all `<ul>` elements, and fires off event callbacks on any element clicked within the `<ul>` elements that matches the `'[data-menu]'` selection.

I don't recommend adding jQuery for the sake of adding jQuery, but jQuery is very useful for managing delegated events. If you're able to take the minor performance hit of downloading an additional library, then it'll make writing code significantly easier.

Comment: Good. I've been messing with the design of this for far too long and I'm not able to see if the overall design and procedure is good. But guess I'll go in this direction. I am not going to add jQuery for this project as that would mean a huge refactoring job. These menus are a rather tiny part. But nice to know the ability of it.

Comment: @user13500, yea, not a big deal. I've been considering writing up an example for how to check the delegate in vanilla JS, but there's enough possible cross-browser issues that I'd be nervous about posting something that wasn't sound. Basically it comes down to checking `e.target.hasAttribute('data-menu')`.